# ruby net/http: How to fix EOFError on HTTPS POST request

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a script to get data from GitHub v4 API. But my Ruby script fails on `EOFError`. How to avoid `EOFError`?

The following code fails on `end of file reached (EOFError)`. I run the script 10 times, but no one suceeded.

```rb
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse 'https://api.github.com/graphql'
header = {
  'Authorization' => 'bearer MY_GITHUB_TOKEN',
}

Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port do |http|
  http.use_ssl = true
end.start do |http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.path, header
  req.body = " \
 { \
   \"query\": \"query { viewer { login }}\" \
 } \
"
  http.request req do |res|
    p res.code
    p res.message
    p res.body
    p res.read_body
    res.read_body do |body|
      p body
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using Ruby `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]`
 compiled by rbenv-build. I got following stack trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        11: from tmp.rb:20:in `<main>'
        10: from /home/yuntan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:920:in `start'
         9: from tmp.rb:31:in `block in <main>'
         8: from /home/yuntan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1479:in `request'
         7: from /home/yuntan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1506:in `transport_request'
         6: from /home/yuntan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1506:in `catch'
         5: from /home/yuntan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1509:in `block in transport_request'
         4: from /home/yuntan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
         3: from /home/yuntan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
         2: from /home/yuntan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:201:in `readline'
         1: from /home/yuntan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:191:in `readuntil'
/home/yuntan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:225:in `rbuf_fill': end of file reached (EOFError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to my wrong guess.

`Net::HTTP.new` does not take any block, so the code below

```rb
Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port do |http|
  http.use_ssl = true
end.start ...
```

should be

```rb
(Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port).tap do |http|
  http.use_ssl = true
end.start ...
```